# TP-Link UE300 on 16.04 server not working as 3.0 device

Tags: networking, server, 16.04, usb, realtek

Hoi!

I am trying to get an TP-Link UE300 USB3.0 to GigaBit ethernet adpater running as a full 3.0 device on an ubuntu 16.04 server.

In principle it works, but for some reason it is claimed by the cdc_driver and used as an USB 2.0 device. That results in a very limited bandwidth and the cdc_driver really doesn't know how to handle the device:

```
root@ff-payload:~# lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2357:0601  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2357:0601  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2357:0601  
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0b05:1825 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Bus 1 devices 2 to 3 are three of these adaptors.
The TP-Link homepage claims that the UE300 uses a realtek RTL8153 chipset but for some reason none of 16.04 kernels realtek drivers feel responsible for the usb device.

Has anybody got a UE300 running as GB ethernet on 16.04 server?

blue skies
Jan Albiez

P.S.: This is the output of a journalctl | grep eth:

```
Sep 14 13:43:45 ff-payload kernel: cdc_ether 1-6:2.0 eth0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:14.0-6, CDC Ethernet Device, f4:f2:6d:18:1f:82
Sep 14 13:43:45 ff-payload kernel: cdc_ether 1-7:2.0 eth1: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:14.0-7, CDC Ethernet Device, f4:f2:6d:18:1e:6d
Sep 14 13:43:45 ff-payload kernel: cdc_ether 1-8:2.0 eth2: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:14.0-8, CDC Ethernet Device, f4:f2:6d:14:06:13
Sep 14 13:43:45 ff-payload kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
Sep 14 13:43:45 ff-payload kernel: cdc_ether 1-6:2.0 enxf4f26d181f82: renamed from eth0
Sep 14 13:43:45 ff-payload kernel: cdc_ether 1-7:2.0 enxf4f26d181e6d: renamed from eth1
Sep 14 13:43:45 ff-payload kernel: cdc_ether 1-8:2.0 enxf4f26d140613: renamed from eth2
```

and: *lsmod | grep r8*:

```
r8152                  49152  0
mii                    16384  2 r8152,usbnet
```

Comment: Incredibly frustrating. I had mine work as a USB 3.0 device the first time I plugged it in, and now have the same problem as you.

Answer (score 1):

Mine is running at USB 3.0 SuperSpeed

```
[  115.388427] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  115.409336] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2357, idProduct=0601
[  115.409343] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=6
[  115.409347] usb 2-1: Product: USB 10/100/1000 LAN
[  115.409350] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: TP-LINK
[  115.409353] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 000000000000
[  115.411273] cdc_ether 2-1:2.0 eth0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, CDC Ethernet Device, xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
[  117.624653] cdc_ether 2-1:2.0 enxd46exxxxxxxx: renamed from eth0
```

This is on Debian Sid with kernel 4.11

But, I'm only getting about 30 to 40 Mbps Ethernet for some odd reason.

Comment: Yeah, the low speed is more due to the `cdc_ether` claiming and handling it rather than the USB protocol used.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a kernel version that has [this fix](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/9d11b06638f6aa30d099090e6b8a540c558295ac) in it. According to Github, that's `4.15-rc1` onwards or `4.14-rc7` onwards.

If you are wary of the recent [bug where some Lenovo machines can be bricked](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1734147) due to an SPI-related module corrupting the UEFI firmware on boot, note that this has been fixed in the `4.15` series (I double checked, but definitely check yourself if you're worried).

You can obtain recent kernels from the [Ubuntu kernel not-really-a-PPA](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/); for example I'm using [`4.15-rc7`](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.15-rc7/) and can confirm that I'm getting substantially better speeds (ten times faster at least, your results will depend upon your own situation). [`4.15-rc8`](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.15-rc8/) was just built, and you can check the parent directory for more recent builds in the future.

I'm sorry but I can't vouch for whether the kernels will install and work with 16.04 (I'm using 17.04). Please let me know if you have any success.

Comment: The USB dongle I used to test this broke, so I didn't continue down that line! But thanks for the help nevertheless!